# Reference the newly added formatcondition?

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to create a formatcondition and set some of its properties:

```
    With r
        .Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
        .FormatConditions.Delete

        'StartDate to StartAdsDate
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(R3C>=RC1343;R3C<=RC1344)"
        With .Interior
            .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
            .Gradient.Degree = 90
            .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
        End With
        With .Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
            .Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With .Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0.5)
            .Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With .Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
            .Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
```

However as the code above is written, .Interior refers to the cells interior, not to the FormatCondition.Interior.

Can the code be rewritten to become cleaner and so that all of the .interior commands actually affect the newly added conditional formatting rule instead of the range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.Add` method actually returns the reference you want:

```
With r
    .Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
    .FormatConditions.Delete

    'StartDate to StartAdsDate
    With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(R3C>=RC1343;R3C<=RC1344)")
        With .Interior
            .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
            .Gradient.Degree = 90
            .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
        End With
        With .Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
            .Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With .Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0.5)
            .Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With .Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
            .Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With
End With
```